# Node js parse query string

Tags: node.js, regex, string, url, query-string

I want "*value*" from the following query string.
by doing request.query.filter i get the following

> "[{\"property\":\"customerId\",\"value\":2,\"exactMatch\":true}]"

tried request.query.filter.value and request.query.filter["value"] but didn't work.

Request URL :

> admin/api/login?action=get&_dc=1547652537836&filter=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22customerId%22%2C%22value%22%3A2%2C%22exactMatch%22%3Atrue%7D%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query string seems to be a JSON string. so the first thing you have to do is convert it to json object to access it.

```
const query = "[{\"property\":\"customerId\",\"value\":2,\"exactMatch\":true}]";
const json = JSON.parse(query);
```

now you can access it with

```
json[0].value
```